# If $f\colon B \to C$ is a bijective function and $g\colon A \to B$ is injective, what can we say about $fg\colon A \to C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I think $fg\colon  A \to C$ is bijective as well but I am not sure. What do you guys think?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If $fg$ is a bijection, then $g=f^{-1}fg$ is also a bijection.

Comment: Try breaking it up: Can you prove $fg$ is surjective? Injective?  Since $f$ has an inverse, what can you say about the existence of $(fg)^{-1}$?

Comment: i understand why it should only be injective. What do you think will happen if $f$ was reduced to being surjective only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- There are injective functions that are not bijective.
- An example of a bijective function $f:B\to C$ is when $B=C$ and $f$ is the identity map.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The composition of injective functions is always injective. Think what happens when $B=C$ and $A$ has a strictly smaller size.